# Issue with TinyMCE v5.9.2 image caption

Tags: image, tinymce, caption

I am using TinyMCE v5.9.2 as the RTE for news articles in a customized CMS.

I am using the advlist, lists, image, imagetools, charmap, preview, anchor, code, link, and paste plugins in the TinyMCE init, and image_caption is set to true.

When I insert an image using drag-n-drop, or clicking the button to select an image, when I check the box for Caption, the image will remain the correct size, but the area outline takes up the whole width of the textarea that is using TinyMCE.  If I resize the caption area, the image scales with it.

I'll try to upload an image, here.

[Image is correct width; caption area is much wider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfMIY.png)

If I go into the source and set a style attribute for the caption to set width, it works, but the user shouldn't have to do that.  Not to mention, it won't resize with the image, if the image is resized.

If switching to v6.0.1 will fix this, I'll do that.  But if it can be fixed in v5, I'd rather not swap out.  Please advise.

V/r,

CFDev2022

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some css to evercome this problem

```
figure.image {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #f3ebeb;
    margin: 0 2px 20px 1px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @ceasar.. that took me a huge step forward!  The caption area does set to the width of the image, and scales perfectly.

I don't have enough reputation to upvote this, but I've been assured that the feedback has been recorded.

V/r,

CFDev2022